# Creating Baseline repository for DMV Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, baseline

I have started to use DMVs to identify the performance issues we have been encountering in our SQL Server.

Has anyone built a repository to capture this DMV data which can be then baselined and compared against the current data moving forward?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of SQL Server? If 2008 you can take a look at the [Management data warehouse.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677306.aspx) Otherwise you could have a look at the [DMVStats](http://sqldmvstats.codeplex.com/) project.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Creating a baseline for SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/sql-server-baseline-creation) to get some ideas

You can not just grab someone's baseline....your server is most likely completely different

Comment: i think OP is looking for a schema that captures the baseline - so he can grab one from his own environment - then compare later..